# Using Pandas to convert JSON to CSV with specific fields

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to convert a JSON file to a CSV file using Pandas.

The codes that I'm using now are able to convert the JSON to a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
json_data = pd.read_json("out1.json")
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(json_data["events"])
df.to_csv("out.csv)
```

This is my JSON file:

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "raw": "{\"level\": \"INFO\", \"message\": \"Disabled camera with QR scan on  by 80801234 at Area A\n\"}",
      "logtypes": [
        "json"
      ],
      "timestamp": 1537190572023,
      "unparsed": null,
      "logmsg": "{\"level\": \"INFO\", \"message\": \"Disabled camera with QR scan on  by 80801234 at Area A\n\"}",
      "id": "c77afb4c-ba7c-11e8-8000-12b233ae723a",
      "tags": [
        "INFO"
      ],
      "event": {
        "json": {
          "message": "Disabled camera with QR scan on  by 80801234 at Area A\n",
          "level": "INFO"
        },
        "http": {
          "clientHost": "116.197.237.29",
          "contentType": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "raw": "{\"level\": \"INFO\", \"message\": \"Employee number saved successfully.\"}",
      "logtypes": [
        "json"
      ],
      "timestamp": 1537190528619,
      "unparsed": null,
      "logmsg": "{\"level\": \"INFO\", \"message\": \"Employee number saved successfully.\"}",
      "id": "ad9c0175-ba7c-11e8-803d-12b233ae723a",
      "tags": [
        "INFO"
      ],
      "event": {
        "json": {
          "message": "Employee number saved successfully.",
          "level": "INFO"
        },
        "http": {
          "clientHost": "116.197.237.29",
          "contentType": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But what I wanted was just some fields (**timestamp**, **level**, **message**) inside the JSON file not all of it.

I have tried a variety of ways:

```
df = json_normalize(json_data["timestamp"]) // gives a KeyError on 'timestamp'

df = json_normalize(json_data, 'timestamp', ['event', 'json', ['level', 'message']]) // TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Where did i went wrong?

Comment: Does `df = df[['timestamp', 'event.json.level', 'event.json.message']]` give what you want after `df = json_normalize(json_data["events"])`?

Comment: @roganjosh It does! Thanks a lot! But do you mind explaining why doesn't my 2nd way of normalizing the data works? I mean it should also be able to extract what i wanted right? Please set your reply as an answer, so I could put a tick to it

Comment: I'm trying to find a better way of doing it, I'm not overly familiar with this method so I'm learning as I go

Comment: Wow, I have to get going now, I'm not sure why I'm struggling with that so much sorry. I need to spend some more time on it but got to go out now. The examples in the docs are not enough for me to understand the nested structure, I'll have to do some more research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `json_normalize` is intended to work on this specific orientation.  I could be wrong but from the documentation, it appears that normalization means "Deal with lists within each dictionary".

Assume `data` is

```
data = json.load(open('out1.json'))['events']
```

Look at the first entry

```
data[0]['timestamp']

1537190572023
```

`json_normalize` wants this to be a list

```
[{'timestamp': 1537190572023}]
```

#### Create augmented `data2`

I don't actually recommend this approach.
If we create `data2` accordingly:

```
data2 = [{**d, **{'timestamp': [{'timestamp': d['timestamp']}]}} for d in data]
```

We can use `json_normalize`

```
json_normalize(
    data2, 'timestamp',
    [['event', 'json', 'level'], ['event', 'json', 'message']]
)

       timestamp event.json.level                                 event.json.message
0  1537190572023             INFO  Disabled camera with QR scan on  by 80801234 a...
1  1537190528619             INFO                Employee number saved successfully.
```

---

#### Comprehension

I think it's simpler to just do

```
pd.DataFrame([
    (d['timestamp'],
     d['event']['json']['level'],
     d['event']['json']['message'])
    for d in data
], columns=['timestamp', 'level', 'message'])

       timestamp level                                            message
0  1537190572023  INFO  Disabled camera with QR scan on  by 80801234 a...
1  1537190528619  INFO                Employee number saved successfully.
```

---

#### `json_normalize`

But without the fancy arguments

```
json_normalize(data).pipe(
    lambda d: d[['timestamp']].join(
        d.filter(like='event.json')
    )
)

       timestamp event.json.level                                 event.json.message
0  1537190572023             INFO  Disabled camera with QR scan on  by 80801234 a...
1  1537190528619             INFO                Employee number saved successfully.
```